# React-dropzone Upload to S3 from client returns 400 bad request

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to implement this code example [here](https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530#.szojl4ui2) to upload an image to an S3 bucket.
My server seems to return the pre-signed URL OK, but the PUT request that follows fails with a 400 error.

Here is the server-side pre-sign code:

```
var s3 = new aws.S3();

    var params = {
        Bucket: secrets.aws.bucket,
        Key: body.filename,
        ContentType: body.filetype,
        ACL: 'public-read'

    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        } else {
          console.log('URL sent back to client ------------------------------------');
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
```

And here is the upload action client-side:

```
export function uploadFile(data) {

  var file = data[0];

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(dropFileAccepted(data));

    return makeUploadRequest('post', {filename: file.name, filetype: file.type}, '/signURLforS3')

        .then(function (result) {
            var signedUrl = result.data;

            var options = {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': file.type,
                'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
                'x-amz-region': 'eu-central-1'
              }
            };
          return axios.put(signedUrl, file, options);
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
  };
}
```

From the network request/response headers it looks like the content-type and CORS configuration on the bucket are correctly set, but I'm unsure whether there could be an issue with needing to set the region. 
or do I need some additional settings on the bucket, like a bucket policy, or specify a Signature version ?

```
Request URL:https://XXXXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/brand.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKXXXXXXXXXXXX&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1460128516&Signature=%2BooCHlrwelBYC9fMYnu01PokgWM%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:54.231.192.36:443 

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, POST, GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3000
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Fri, 08 Apr 2016 15:00:17 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2:rXMCu6YD5mLrN3beBCs+kmXDGzhzrQHV2fTUTNooWXBQuPfLNOKDcArGQWRj+NLk+zo=
x-amz-region:eu-central-1
x-amz-request-id:FC181ED154

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr-FR;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:16819
Content-Type:image/png
Host:XXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/admin/blog/create
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
x-amz-acl:public-read
x-amz-region:eu-central-1

Query String Params
AWSAccessKeyId:AKXXXXXXXX
Content-Type:image/png
Expires:1460128516
Signature:+ooCHlrwelBYu01PokgWM=
x-amz-acl:public-read
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers. I've been pulling my hair out over this...

Comment: I solved this issue by setting the signature version to V4, as S3 buckets in the region eu-central-1 use V4....the server-side pre-sign code needs the following config: aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: secrets.aws.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: secrets.aws.secretKey,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'eu-central-1'
});

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and had to install and setup a proxy so I could see the actual response body (as Chrome does not show it to you). The problem I had was that `react-dropzone-s3-uploader` defaults to adding a header to the upload to S3 that is:

`x-amz-acl: public`

Which is fine if you want to have public uploads but if you're setting an ACL on the presigned URL for the upload that does not match this one, the HTTP PUT of the file will have a HTTP 400 error with this as the response body (again, need a proxy to see the response body as Chrome/browser do not show it):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
  <Message>Conflicting values provided for argument: x-amz-acl</Message>
  <RequestId>...</RequestId>
  <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

The solution is to include an `uploadRequestHeaders` key like so in the `upload` prop passed into the component:

```
          upload={{
            ...
            uploadRequestHeaders: {
              'x-amz-acl': 'private',
            },
          }}
```

Of course, set the value of `x-amz-acl` to your desired ACL.

Reference https://github.com/founderlab/react-dropzone-s3-uploader/blob/master/src/DropzoneS3Uploader.js#L92

Comment: https://mitmproxy.org/ work greated as a proxy -- just have to install the certificates too so you can use it with SSL/secure sites.

Comment: Oh, and I did try adding the `signatureVersion: "v4"` option but that didn't help and I ended up leaving it out. This just broke roughly in July 2022 but my code hadn't changed and `react-dropzone-s3-uploader` hadn't changed so presumably something changed on AWS S3 (but not certain).